# Is there any way around Python's lack of block commenting?

Tags: python, comments

To be honest, this isn't anything dire, I just can't find anything on the web about it. I'm working on a big project right now in Python, and I need to comment out a large chunk of code for the moment until it can be implemented. It's about 500+ lines, so I'd *really* rather not have to go through one by one adding '#''s if possible. I've seen posts on here stating the lack of block commenting built in, but is there any way to sort of emulate this, or get the same effect easily of commenting out a large section of code?

Comment: Your editor can't do this for you automatically? Time for a new editor.

Comment: `""" code """` fails in the case where the code already includes a triple-quoted string, such as a docstring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a decent text editor. Sublime Text lets me select a block and comment it out; `#` will be inserted on every line, and another command lets me revert the commenting.

If you are stuck with no decent editor, you could use a triple-quoted string:

```
"""This part turned into a string to ease commenting out
if ...:
    # 500 lines

""" # end of block string.
```

This will create a giant string object, that is then not assigned to anything. You do need to make sure that the opening quotes are indented properly, and that the line following the closing quotes has valid indentation too.

Of course, this presumes that you don't have a triple-quoted string using the same quoting style in those 500 lines already; you can capture `'''` blocks in `"""` quotes and vice-versa, but if you have existing text blocks using both styles, you'll have to escape those manually.

Comment: ...and that the big commented block doesn't have `"""` quotes strings in it.

Comment: @Wooble if for some reason it DOES have `"""` in it, you can change your outside quotes to triple single quotes: `'''` , if your giant 'comment' has `'''` and `"""` in it, may god help your soul.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably get away with putting it into a multi-line string. Or maybe indent it and put the whole thing under:

```
if False:
```

so that you can easily toggle it.

But really, this is an editor's job. I have never seen a code editor that can't comment all lines in a selection.